# Filtering SQLAlchemy query on attribute_mapped_collection field of relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two classes, Tag and Hardware, defined with a simple parent-child relationship (see the full definition at the end).

Now I want to filter a query on Tag using the version field in Hardware through an attribute_mapped_collection, eg:

```
def get_tags(order_code=None, hardware_filters=None):
    session = Session()
    query = session.query(Tag)
    if order_code:
        query = query.filter(Tag.order_code == order_code)
    if hardware_filters:
        for k, v in hardware_filters.iteritems():
            query = query.filter(getattr(Tag.hardware, k).version == v)
    return query.all()
```

But I get:

`AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with Tag.hardware has an attribute 'baseband`

The same thing happens if I strip it back by hard-coding the attribute, eg:

`query.filter(Tag.hardware.baseband.version == v)`

I can do it this way:

`query = query.filter(Tag.hardware.any(artefact=k, version=v))`

But why can't I filter directly through the attribute?

**Class definitions**

```
class Tag(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tag'
    tag_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    order_code = Column(String, nullable=False)
    version = Column(String, nullable=False)
    status = Column(String, nullable=False)
    comments = Column(String)
    hardware = relationship(
        "Hardware",
        backref="tag",
        collection_class=attribute_mapped_collection('artefact'),
    )
    __table_args__ = (
        UniqueConstraint('order_code', 'version'),
    )

class Hardware(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'hardware'
    hardware_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    tag_id = Column(String, ForeignKey('tag.tag_id'))
    product_id = Column(String, nullable=True)
    artefact = Column(String, nullable=False)
    version = Column(String, nullable=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you compose a query, we're ultimately composing SQL.  What SQL do you think would be rendered from an expression such as `filter(Tag.hardware.baseband)`?  There's no simple answer to that, and SQLAlchemy never makes any guesses as to how traversing along multiple paths like that would work.  The usage of `attribute_mapped_collection` is only relevant to the in-Python manipulation of objects and has no effect on how SQL is rendered for this attribute.  Hence you need to use a construct that maps directly to SQL, in this case the ANY() seems like a good choice.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I eventually realized what you said is true; it needs to be expressible in SQL. I went with joins in the end, since I understand them clearly. Since I'm new to SQLAlchemy, and ORM in general, I'm still getting a feel for it. At the moment, I have to think "how would I write this with SQL?" and then try to understand the SQLAlchemy docs until I can achieve that. I can see how SQLAlchemy queries can be more flexible and easy to compose than text based SQL queries in Python, but I'm still working my way up the learning curve.